# Issue Converting Older MITMProxy Scripts to work on 5.2 - Error on Replace and Can't Find Docs on What Replaced was Replaced with

Tags: python, mitmproxy

I Updated to MITMProxy Version 5.2.
After updating I tried to run an Older Script and Kept Getting the Error:

```
AttributeError: 'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

From my code:

```
flow.response.replace('FindThis', 'ReplaceWithThis')
```

I read that they Change Replace, but couldn't find any documents that were CLEAR on what they changed it to or the correct Syntax in a Script.

I read `ModifyBody` was a replacement, but when I changed my script from `replace` to `ModifyBody`, I would then get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'ModifyBody'
```

So I assume it is not correct or I need to load a module? And i would like to know if there is a new or same Syntax.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We removed `HTTPResponse.replace` because it wasn't really clear which parts (headers, content) were replaced how. In practical terms:

- Use `flow.response.content = flow.response.content.replace(b"foo", b"bar")` to make binary replacements in the response body.
- Use `flow.response.text = flow.response.text.replace("foo", "bar")` to make text replacements in the response body.
- Use `flow.headers` as a dictionary to make header replacements, e.g. `flow.headers["foo"] = "42"`.